# Force Firefox to Reload Page on Back Button

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, caching

How do you make Firefox rerun javascript and reload the entire page when the user presses the back button?  I was able to do this in all browsers except Firefox from the help of another SO question by adding this code:

```
history.navigationMode = 'compatible';
$("body").unload(function(){})
```

And also adding an iFrame...  But this doesn't work in Firefox.  Is there anything to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add this between your HEAD tags

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

Comment: Note: This solution does not work. At least not in recent Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: As to why it doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314174/difference-between-pragma-and-cache-control-headers

Answer (score 8):

In my case, after the final user Post his new data to server, he is redirected to another page. But when the final user press the back button, the form is pre-populated with the old data. So, reload page is needed.

I did a workaround for Firefox and another for Google Chrome. They have different behavior to show cached pages.

Doing this will prevent Firefox to cache the page and the back button will bring the page from server.

```
window.onunload = function(){};
```

But Google Chrome do it in another way and the solution above did not work for me. So I did another workaround for Chrome. I did a flag that mark the form as dirty.

At the top of `<head>`, before load anything, I check the cookie

```
if(document.cookie.match(/my-form=dirty/)) {
  document.cookie = "my-form=; expires=-1; path="+document.location.pathname;
  window.location.reload();
}
```

With a help of jQuery, I write the cookie when user modify something

```
$(document).load(function(){
  $(':input').change(function(){
    document.cookie = "my-form=dirty; expires=86400000; path="+document.location.pathname;
  })
})
```

Good to know:

- http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2636
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching

Comment: window.onunload=function() {} worked for me in conjunction with Angular. Adding meta tags as in the previous answer did not.

Answer (score 5):

This solution worked for me (and I believe is a bit simpler than other solutions suggested):

```
    $(window).bind('pageshow', function() {
        // This event is called only by FireFox. Because Firefox doesn't reload the page when the user uses the back button,
        // or when we call history.go.back(), we need to force the reload for the applicatino to work similar to Chrome and IE (11 at least).

        // Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Listening_to_events_in_Firefox_extensions
        location.reload();
    });
```

I call this code on every page load, if the browser is FireFox. (To find out if the currently running browser is Firefox, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000190/detect-all-firefox-versions-in-js)).

Comment: Sorry, but it is a loop. What is the idea?

Answer (score 3):

For reference, that navigationMode property only applies to Opera, it's just that IE and the Webkit browsers already have the behavior the questioner wanted.

IE and Webkit do what Opera would call "compatible" navigation. Firefox does what Opera would call "fast" navigation. But it's only in Opera that this behavior is actually controllable.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to you file. Clean your cache first before testing.

```
<?php
 header("Cache-Control: private, no-store, max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
?>
```

to add headers in javascript please read this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/append

Answer (score 0):

None of this worked for me. I do it via cookies checking - I import jsp (source below) in head part of page, and then I call refreshOnBack in .

```
<%@ page import="java.util.UUID" %>
<script>
    var REFRESH_PAGE_COOKIE_NAME="refreshPage_";
    var PAGE_REFRESH_GUID = "<%out.print(UUID.randomUUID().toString());%>";  
    /* To force refresh of page when user or javascript clicks "back",
     * put call to this method in body onload function - NOT THROUGH JQUERY 
     * as jquery onload is not called on history back.
     * In must be done via <BODY onload="...">
     */
    function refreshOnBack(){
        //Alghoritm uses cookies to check if page was already loaded.
        //Cookies expiration time is not set - will be gone after browser restart.
        //Alghoritm:
        //is cookie set? 
        // -YES - reload;
        // -NO - set it up;
        //Cookie contains unique guid in name so that when page is regenerated - it will not reload.
        var cookieName = REFRESH_PAGE_COOKIE_NAME + PAGE_REFRESH_GUID; 
        if(getCookie(cookieName)=="Y"){
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            setCookie(cookieName,"Y");
        }
    }   
</script>
```

Comment: how do you call refreshOnBack?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you might want is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5493543/1475148

TLDR: HTTPS + `Cache-Control: must-revalidate` as a server-sent header + `Expires` header set in the past should make it work. Here’s a sample PHP implementation:

```
<?php

$expires = gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s', time() - 1 );

header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate' );
header( "Expires: {$expires} GMT" );

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Auto-reloading page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>The current day is <?php echo date( 'd, F Y'); ?> and the time is <?php echo date('H:i:s'); ?>.</p>
        <p><a href="http://google.com">Click away</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using c# .Net, you can handle it on the page load or init event programmatically

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
Response.Cache.VaryByParams["*"] = true;
```

For more info, check out Response.Cache at MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cache(v=vs.110).aspx