# Modernizr checks to detect firefox

Tags: javascript, modernizr

What are the possible checks can be made to detect firefox features using modernizr?

Comment: Browser detection is not recommended more. Feature detection is the way forward. As such, Modernizr won't let you do it; you'll have to inspect the `userAgent` string manually and check yourself (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000190/detect-all-firefox-versions-in-js)

Comment: The entire point of Modernizr is to perform feature detection instead of client-agent detection.  There may be a way to do it, but it's contrary to the larger aim of the tool.

Comment: Are you satisfied with a method which matches all browsers which are using the Gecko layout engine?

Comment: If browser detection shouldn't be used, then what about the way IE doesn't trigger a change event on making a selection from a list type input until removing focus?

Comment: IE7 and under, that is. The kind that leads to code like this: 
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 8)
  input.bind('click', function () {
    $(this).trigger('change');
  });

Comment: The best answer I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Browser detection is unfortunately still necessary for things like video and audio since all browsers promote different formats. I think you'll find your answer here, Natto:

http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html

Answer (score 19):

Even if browser detection is not recommended for features it could be use to present other type of information.

```
Modernizr.addTest('firefox', function () {
 return !!navigator.userAgent.match(/firefox/i);
});
```

This adds a class .firefox to document.documentElement (html tag)

Comment: Unfortunately some features are implemented differently on each browser...

Comment: Sometimes you have to check for bugs in *implemented* features.