# Any Possible way to add more than one favicon in a website

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

how to add more than a singe favicon for different browser?

### Reason:

[image]

[Google Chrome] favicon matches perfectly at horizontal axis with page title to make "AT Drive" a complete sentence!

[image: Mozilla Firefox]

[Mozilla Firefox] Now here you can see the "Same favicon" miss matched the horizontal axis, it shifted little downwards

### What i want:

To insert Multi-Favicon icons in a website with respect to browsers..

Comment: I have never tried this, but you can try to dynamically create favicon using a script according to which browser is making the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can`t think of any pure html/css solution but You can change favicon for specify browser via JavaScript.

For example detect if browser is firefox ([Detect all Firefox versions in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000190/detect-all-firefox-versions-in-js)) and then set diferent favicon for it ([Changing website favicon dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically)) so final code should look something like this

```
<link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />

 <script type="text/javascript">

    if (/firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        document.getElementById("favicon").href = "favicon-firefox.png";
    }

</script>
```