# Any code to open a webpage only in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a webpage but due to some reasons I want it to only open in Firefox browser.
If opened in anyother browser like IE or chrome it automatically redirect to the page in which I can show message.

Comment: So you're saying you want to detect which browser the user is using?

Comment: what if the user does not have ff and he has only chrome and ie or safari ...... its an unlikely option to open only in FF ......

Comment: I'm curious: _Why_ do you need this page to only work in FF?

Answer (score -1):

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1){
   location.href = 'www.your.domain.com';
}
```

[Detect Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000190/detect-all-firefox-versions-in-js)

Comment: Please don't answer questions that have been answered a hundred times already. Mark the question as duplicate, instead.