# How to show/hide a jquery script only on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, browser, cross-browser

Trying to show and hide js only on Firefox browser. *There are another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000190) about Detect all Firefox versions, but it is not answer of my question so i have asked this question.*

*HTML:*

```
<div id="about_me">
This Text color will be change
</div>
```

*Show this only on Firefox:*

```
$("#about_me").addClass("red");
```

*I have trying this but not working:*

```
<!--[if Gecko ]>
$("#about_me").addClass("red");
<![endif]-->
```

*And Show this to other browsers and hide on Firefox:*

```
$("#about_me").addClass("blue");
```

How show JS to different browser, that text color will be red only on Firefox and blue on other browsers.

Please See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9gzcsvm/) >>  
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000190/detect-all-firefox-versions-in-js

Comment: @Jeremy Thille no this is totally different topic. That was versions Detection. :)

Comment: Uh no, that's about Firefox detection, using `if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1)`. Not so "totally different" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with **navigator.userAgent** used to detect the browser

> The userAgent property returns the value of the user-agent header sent
>   by the browser to the server.
>
> The value returned, contains information about the name, version and
>   platform of the browser.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox") > -1){
    $("#about_me").addClass("red");
}
else{    
    $("#about_me").addClass("blue");    
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d9gzcsvm/4/)

[**About Naviagate Useragent  | MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent)

Note : **Run the fiddle in all browsers**. I checked in chrome, safari, IE and firefox

Comment: Thanks, you have not use `toLowerCase()` there are any possibilities to any error? some browsers give the userAgent in uppercase or captialize.

Comment: Please change Firefox to firefox, bcz it's not working.

Comment: @Aabira - Thanks for the update i forgot it actually

Answer (score 1):

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1)
{
$("#about_me").addClass("red");
}
```

Alternatively you can use like this also

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') > -1)
{
$("#about_me").addClass("red");
}
```

Comment: Although it may work, not sure it's simpler than `if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1)`.

Comment: @Techy fiddle please.

Comment: @Techy  Not me dear, i think it's "Jeremy Thille"

Comment: @Techy please give a fiddle from my question. i will Up-vote, and accept you Ans.

Comment: @Aabira Suppose some browsers give the userAgent in uppercase or captialize we don't know exactly what browser throw. SOo we prevently alert use toLowercase() for the userAgent make it all string as lowercase

Comment: For example FIREFOX, Firefox it comes using toLowerCase() is 'firefox'

Comment: navigator.userAgent returns data with Firefox as string.You can use without toLocaleLowerCase() also.But you need to change the string as Firefox

Comment: @Aabira i have explained and changed the answer also.Hope you understood

Answer (score 1):

It should work:

HTML:

```
<br>
<div id="about_me">
     This Text color will be change
</div>e here
```

CSS:

```
.red { color: red; }
.blue { color: blue; }
```

JS:

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLocaleLowerCase();  

if(userAgent.indexOf('firefox') > -1) {
    $("#about_me").addClass("red");
} else {
    $("#about_me").addClass("blue"); 
}
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/pyg9ynb5/2/

Comment: About the `toLocaleLowerCase()` it's just to lowercase the entire user agent string. Actually, it's not need, you can remove if you want and compare with 'Firefox' on if statement.

If it's ok for you, please accept my answer as correct.