# How could I show animated svg in some browsers, but static svg or png in firefox?

Tags: firefox, animation, browser, svg

I have an animated svg, but firefox doesn't currently support the transform-origin  property with % for svgs.  So I'd like to hide the animated svg and show a static svg or png when users view in firefox.  I'm not sure how to do this.  I don't think feature detection will work, because firefox does support svgs and transform-origin, just not transform-origin for svg.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Just wait till December 15, Firefox 43 released then supports percentages on transform-origin. That's only 17 days away at the time of writing.

Comment: Yeah I had heard this, but my concern is that many users won't have updated their version of Firefox and so the problem would still persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had this issue. I remember reading a comment somewhere in SO that Firefox42 supports this with a prefix:

```
  -moz-transform-origin
```

anyway, to detect firefox i use a snippet found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000190/detect-all-firefox-versions-in-js?lq=1):

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1)
 {
     //Do Firefox-related activities
 }
```

in your case, if the browser is indeed firefox, and assuming you are using 2 container elements, 1 for your SVG and one for your PNG, you could:

1) directly add/show the elements with js

2) add a 'firefox' class to your root html element and style your css accordingly.

so, let's say you have a #svg and #png containers

in your css you'd use:

```
.firefox #png { display: block; }
#png { display: none; }
#svg { display: block; }
.firefox #svg { display: none; }
```

Hope this helps!