# jquery load function not calling after the first call

Tags: jquery

I am using the `JQuery` load() `$("#list").load("test.do");`. it works fine when we I load the page for the frist time. but after that if i navigate back to some other module and come to back this page. load function does not fetching the updated content ie not calling the test.do again. Any help?

Thanks in advance

Kumar

Comment: Provide some code, or a jsfiddle, so we can understand what you've done.

Comment: have you confirmed there are no scripting errors taking place? Are you using debugging tools in the browser to set break points to verify whats going on?

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue. Take a look at this article:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536822/force-firefox-to-reload-page-on-back-button

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
   $("#list").load("test.do");
});
```

try with this. add this to your code.