# Firefox Document Expired Issue over https

Tags: firefox, caching, back, no-cache

I have a site that is running a combination of Perl and HTML.

I've got a problem with the search function, where after I've searched for a keyword, and clicked the back button I get the Firefox "Document Expired" page.

I've read several posts online and tried out a number of ways of fixing it, including putting in the pragma no-cache meta tags.

[Force Firefox to Reload Page on Back Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536822/force-firefox-to-reload-page-on-back-button)

I've been told by another developer that as the page is over https then there is nothing I can do to prevent this from happening as the browser is designed to prevent the information history for another user from being accessed.

I'd just like to either confirm that this is correct and that there's nothing I can do about it, or if not whether anyone has any suggestions for workarounds that I might not have read about.